# Why my jsp page values are not loaded into my action with a link method

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have an JSP page which has multiple buttons and a link all of which call methods in my action java page (code is below).  When I click on a button, the action's prepare method is called, followed by the setters for the JSP page values, followed by the method attached to the button.  But when I click on the link the prepare method is called, followed by the method attached to the link.  The setters aren't called so I can't access any of the JSP page values.  Is there a way around this issue?  Thanks for any help!

```
<s:form action = "commentAction" validate="true" method="post" id="commentAction" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <s:if test="%{showAddButton == true}">
        <s:submit method="add" key="button.add" cssClass="submit" onclick="clearDirtyFlag();" tabindex="15"/>
    </s:if>
    <s:if test="%{showSaveButton == true}">
        <s:submit method="save" key="button.save" cssClass="submit" onclick="clearDirtyFlag();" tabindex="16"/>
    </s:if>
    <s:submit method="reset" key="button.clear" cssClass="submit" onclick="clearDirtyFlag(); document.getElementById('commentAction').reset();"  tabindex="17"/>

    <s:iterator value="commentViewList" >
        <s:url var="commentLink" action="commentAction" method="getCommentDetails">
            <s:param name="commentId"><s:property value="commentInfo.commentId"/></s:param>
        </s:url>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-12 text-left"><s:a href="%{commentLink}"  tabindex="18"><s:property value="commentTypeCode"/></s:a></div>
    </s:iterator> 
</s:form>
```

Comment: Plain link won't submit a form. Use js or style submit as link. See I haven't edited this question, yet. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  What is style submit?  I tried a google search and didn't find anything.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can use css to make button look like a link.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That I can find out how to do.