# Saving page field values with Struts2 using javascript with a link

Tags: javascript, struts2

I know from a previous question [(page values are not loaded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556431/why-my-jsp-page-values-are-not-loaded-into-my-action-with-a-link-method) I can't use a link to submit a form.  I either need to make a button look like a link or use JavaScript.  I have the following link inside of an iterator.

```
    <s:iterator value="chosenShipperViewList">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-left">
            <s:url var="deleteLink"><s:param name="shipperName" value="%{organizationInfo.orgName}"></s:param></s:url>
            <s:a id="deleteShipper" onclick="deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList();" href="%{deleteLink}" > 
                <img    src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Map Red X" >
            </s:a>
        </div>
        <hr>
</s:iterator>
```

The JavaScript function is

```
function deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList(){
if(confirmDelete()){
        var oldAction = document.getElementById("shipment").action;
        var url = oldAction.replace("shipment","shipment"+"_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList");
        document.forms[0].action = url;
        document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

};

The only field value which makes it to the java action page is the `shipperName` which is passed as a parameter so I obviously am not using the JavaScript function correctly with the link.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AleksandrM Do  you want me to show all of the jsp code for the form?  I don't mind but it is 400 lines of code.

Comment: A single form is 400 lines of code? Something is wrong here. Maybe you should split it up to some kind of a wizard. Anyway, you're saying that one js works and the other one doesn't? What the difference between them?

Comment: If I call the JavaScript function from a select  e.g. `<s:select name="shipper" list="list" onchange="getshipperInformation()"/>` it works.  When I call the same JavaScript function from an anchor e.g.`<s:a onclick="getshipperInformation()"/>` It doesn't work.  The form values are not saved by Struts.

Comment: Problem is inside `href`. You need to stop default event action. E.g in js `preventDefault()`.

Comment: The W3 Schools example for `preventDefault` is `document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});`  The id's for the `<a>` elements are generated dynamically.  Do I need to pass the id as a parameter to the js function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future googler's this is what I did to solve my problem.  I was using the link so I could access the `orgid` of the shipper the user wanted to delete but I couldn't figure out a way to save all of the page field values the user had entered before he deleted a shipper.  So I took the advice Aleksandr M. gave on a previous question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556431/why-my-jsp-page-values-are-not-loaded-into-my-action-with-a-link-method) and changed the link to a submit which I displayed as an image (a red X).

```
<s:iterator value="chosenShipperViewList" status="status">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 "><label class="pull-right"><s:text name="name"></s:text>:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12  text-left"><s:property value="organizationInfo.orgName"/></div>  
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-12  text-left">
            <s:submit action="shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList" type="image" 
                        src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" 
                        onclick="clearDirtyFlag();deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList('%{organizationInfo.orgId}');" />
        </div>  
        <hr>
</s:iterator>
```

Passing `'%{organizationInfo.orgId}'` to the `deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList()` function allowed me to pass the `orgId` for the shipper the user wanted to delete to the function. Using a `<s:submit>` instead of a link meant `Struts` would take care of saving any values the user had entered.  To get the value to the Java action page `deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList()` stored it in a hidden field as follows:

```
function deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList(orgIdOfShipperToRemove){
  if(confirmDelete()){
    document.getElementById('shipment_deleteOrgId').value = orgIdOfShipperToRemove;
}};
```

where the hidden field is:

```
<s:hidden name="deleteOrgId"></s:hidden>
```

and is inside the `<s:form action="shipment">` form which is why the id of the hidden form is `shipment_deleteOrgId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a second way, which you have tried.

The code is using `url` tag to create a link for delete action, which has required parameter.

```jsp
<s:url var="deleteLink"><s:param name="shipperName" value="%{organizationInfo.orgName}"/></s:url>
```

---

You should use this URL in the javascript code to modify the action attribute before `submit()` is called.

You can pass this URL to the function as a parameter.

```jsp
<s:a id="deleteShipper" onclick="deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList('%{#deleteLink}');" href="#" > 
  <img src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Map Red X" >
</s:a>
```

---

Now you should use a parameter with `deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList()` function

```js
function deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList(url){
  if (confirmDelete()) {        
     document.forms[0].action = url;
     document.forms[0].submit();
  }
}
```

---

Comment: I don't think this solves my issue.  I have edited my question to try to make it clearer what my problem is.